# Textures Don't Line Up in the UV Image Editor

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to apply the texture the model came with but when I would smart project the model onto a new UV image, the texture wouldn't match the unwrapped model at all. Photo on what I mean below...
[image]

Comment: if your model has seams you should use the simple "Unwrap" mode

Comment: Why don't you use the UV map that comes with the model? If you unwrap the model again, the original map gets obviously destroyed.

Comment: This texture is what came with the model. It just doesn't line up...

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us a little more about the model? If the UV is broken already in the original, then it's not a .blend file and there's also no magic button that can fix it. So, what format is it?, Where did you get it from? You can use the edit link below your question to add sufficient information.

Comment: and metaphor_set already explained that the UV mapping comes with the model, and when you unwrap it, you are doing it again and breaking the UV alignment to the provided texture.

Comment: I gotcha. The model was provided by someone from a forum. It's an .FBX model that just came with a lot of textures...